# How to reset flow collect or cancel job

Tags: android, kotlin

I use flow kotlin for countdown Timer (10 seconds). for the first time it is working but after that if I want to reset it , it behaves weird.
10 seconds faster than usual to near 0. after I added job , nothing has changed. how to reset it ?

viewmodel:

```
    lateinit var job: Job
   private var countDownFlow :Flow<Int> = flow<Int>{

        currentvalue = startingvalue
        emit(startingvalue)
        while(currentvalue>=0)
         {
            delay(1000L)
             currentvalue -= 1
            if(currentvalue >=0)
            emit(currentvalue)
            else{
                resendActive.value = true
                job.cancel()
                }
         }
        }

        init {
            setCurrentTime()
            collectFlow()
        } 




 fun collectFlow()
        {
            job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                countDownFlow.cancellable().buffer().collect { time ->

                Log.d("collectflow", "collect $time")
                currentTime.value = String.format("%02d:%02d", (time % 3600) / 60, (time % 60))
            }
        }

    }
```

for resetting collecting
fragment:

```
 binding.otpviewmodel.collectFlow()
```

Log Debug:

```
2022-02-06 16:24:09.887 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 10
2022-02-06 16:24:10.575 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 9
2022-02-06 16:24:10.831 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 8
2022-02-06 16:24:11.596 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 7
2022-02-06 16:24:11.832 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 6
2022-02-06 16:24:12.597 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 5
2022-02-06 16:24:12.836 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 4
2022-02-06 16:24:13.601 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 3
2022-02-06 16:24:13.839 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 2
2022-02-06 16:24:14.604 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 1
2022-02-06 16:24:14.841 18087-18087  D/collectflow: collect 0
```

Comment: do you call `collectFlow()` from different places? Or just from `init {}` block.

Comment: I would move the `currentValue` property into a local variable inside the `flow` builder block so it can't be shared by multiple uses of the flow. The logic of the countdown looks very convoluted as well. I think it could be rewritten in just a few lines. I don't understand why it needs to cancel the job that's collecting it when it's done anyway. Like this: `val countdownFlow = flow { for (i in startingValue downTo 1) { emit(i); delay(1000) }; emit(0) }`

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks. I used job because I thought previous collectflow() in init{ } Interfered to new one that was called from fragment and wrong emitted value for that.  it is worked now. yeah you are right. code structure was complex. now I changed to yours. and call "collectFlow" for collecting again in fragment.

Comment: @Sergey Yeah. for first time called it from init{} viewmodel then called from fragment. the problem is fixed by above comment.